# Replace specific values in a data frame except first column

Tags: r, replace

I have this line in one my function - `result[result>0.05] <- ""`, that replaces all values from my data frame grater than 0.05, including the row names from the first column. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fast way too:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100),nrow=10))
df[-1][df[-1]>0.05] <- ''
```

Output:

```
> df
           V1 V2                 V3 V4 V5 V6                 V7 V8 V9                V10
1  0.60105471                                                                           
2  0.63340567                                                                           
3  0.11625581                                                                           
4  0.96227379                                                         0.0173133104108274
5  0.07333583                                                                           
6  0.05474430                                0.0228175506927073                         
7  0.62610309                                                                           
8  0.76867090                                                                           
9  0.76684615    0.0459537433926016                                                     
10 0.83312158
```